# How to take input and show output in vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I can take inputs and show outputs in the following type of vector:

```
vector<pair<int,int>>
```

But the type :

```
vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>
```

is confusing me.
I need this data type to store Graph information on which I intend to do Depth First Search traversal.

I tried compiling the following code. But after compilation, the program crashes. I will be thankful if someone corrects this code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
typedef vector<vii> vvii;
typedef vector<int> vi;

vvii AdjList;

int main()
{
    ii val;
    val.first=4,val.second=10;
    AdjList[0].push_back(val);
    cout<<AdjList[0][0].first;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that `AdjList` starts out *empty*. Any indexing into it, even index `0`, is out of bounds. You need to start by pushing back a vector into it (i.e. your type-alias `vii`).

Comment: [OT] Using `ii`, `vii`, `vvii`, and `vi` for type names, IMHO, is not a good idea.  Makes the code very hard to figure out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks dude! Your idea worked. :)
But is there any way I can directly push values into a nested vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver I used those typedefs for the code to look compact. However, will keep your words in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
typedef vector<vii> vvii;
vvii AdjList(1000);


int main()
{
    ii val;
    val.first=4,val.second=10;
    AdjList[0].push_back(val);
    cout<<AdjList[0][0].first;
    return 0;
}
```